# Is there any way to tell ncrunch to use the same configuration for multiple solutions?

Tags: ncrunch

Relatively simple question, I think.  We use TFS as source control, with a feature-branching strategy.  Every time we create a new branch, NCrunch pops up to tell us to configure it.  Since the solution is really the same one, I'd like to have some sort of way to tell NCrunch to use the same configuration each time.  Is that possible?